# Primer heterodimer problem

Tags: molecular-biology, bioinformatics, pcr, primer

I design my primers in Primer3PLUS and analyze them in Oligoanalyzer3.1, A big problem that I have this is that I got very nice output in NCBI-Primer BLAST for their specificity but a very negative ΔG for self or hetrodimer even under -7 or-13. is it possible use them for PCR by adding DMSO or Formamide? what other way may be helpful?

Comment: Is it possible for you to provide the primer sequences. Sometimes it may not really matter because the primer dimer may not be extended by the polymerase. What is the Tm of primer-template and primer-primer pairs. You may not need DMSO at all.